# Ionic 4: popover does not work with right floating

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I am trying to show popover when the user click on a button. However, when I position the button to right of the screen, the popover does not show up.

This works, file: `basket.page.html`

```js
<ion-button slot="icon-only" shape="round" fill="outline" (click)="presentPopover($event)" >
          <ion-icon button size="large" name="more"></ion-icon>
        </ion-button>
        <ion-card-title>
          {{ basket.name }}
        </ion-card-title>
```

[image]

but this does not work, when I click on the button, the popover does not show up. I just added `class="float-right"` to `ion-button` tag.

```js
<ion-button class="float-right" slot="icon-only" shape="round" fill="outline" (click)="presentPopover($event)" >
          <ion-icon button size="large" name="more"></ion-icon>
        </ion-button>
        <ion-card-title>
          {{ basket.name }}
        </ion-card-title>
```

[image]

I have this in `basket.page.ts`

```js
async presentPopover(ev: any) {
    this.popover = await this.popoverController.create({
      component: PopoverComponent,
      event: ev,
      translucent: true,
      componentProps: { basketId: this.basketId }
    });
    return await this.popover.present();
  }
```

Comment: can you post your code on stackblitz  ?

Comment: @KhanhLeTran unfortunately, I can't do that for this project. if you know reason that may cause this to happen, please, let me know.

Comment: give me some detail about the ioncard. Ex: `<div>  <ion-button class="float-right" slot="icon-only" shape="round" fill="outline" (click)="presentPopover($event)" >
          <ion-icon button size="large" name="more"></ion-icon>
        </ion-button>
        <ion-card-title>
          {{ basket.name }}
        </ion-card-title>
</div>` , i need the detail about <div> like my example

Comment: it is just an ionic component

Comment: can you give me the detail of class "float-right" ? i'm creating an example to test what happened.

Comment: `float-right` is a class in bootstrap library (CSS library). check it out here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/float/

Comment: "this.popover" where you create this variable ? assign in constructor or just a component variable ?

Comment: `this.popover` is class variable `popover = null;`

Comment: everything is fine. can you run your code again and share information of the console log ? maybe there are some errors there.